# If $f(x)=\int_1^x\frac{\tan^{-1}t}t\,\mathrm dt$, find $f(e^2)-f(\frac1{e^2})$

Tags: definite-integrals

> If $$f(x)=\int_1^x\frac{\tan^{-1}t}{t}\,\mathrm dt,$$
>   find $f(e^2)-f\left(\dfrac{1}{e^2}\right)$.

I think that Newton-Leibniz formula should be applied but the problem is that that if I apply it, I would get $f'(x)$ but I have to find the answer in terms of $f(e^2)$ which involves no derivatives.

How to go about it?

Comment: This is just $\int_{1/e^2}^{e^2}\frac{\tan^{-1}t}{t}dt$

Comment: @W.mu How do I apply Newton Leibniz here?

Comment: I don't think that this problem has relation to the theorem.

Comment: @W.mu How can I do it without applying that?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=intgral+arctan(t)%2Ft,+%5B1%2Fe%5E2,e%5E2%5D

Comment: Hint: Integrate by parts and substitute the limit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f(x)-f(1/x)$.
Then
$$g'(x)=f'(x)+\frac{f'(1/x)}{x^2}
=\frac{\tan^{-1}x}x+\frac{\tan^{-1}(1/x)}x=\frac{\pi}{2x}.$$
As $g(1)=0$ then $g(x)=\frac\pi2\ln x$. In particular,
$g(e^2)=\pi$.

Answer (score 5):

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$Note that $\arctan \dfrac{1}{x} = \dfrac{π}{2} - \arctan x$ for any $x > 0$, then\begin{align*}
f\left( \frac{1}{x} \right) &= \int_1^{\textstyle \frac{1}{x}} \frac{\arctan t}{t} \,\d t = \int_1^x \frac{\dfrac{π}{2} - \arctan u}{\dfrac{1}{u}} · \left( -\frac{1}{u^2} \right) \,\d u\\
&= -\frac{π}{2} \int_1^x \frac{\d u}{u} + \int_1^x \frac{\arctan u}{u} \,\d u = -\frac{π}{2} \ln x + f(x).
\end{align*}